# Google map search region with my own highlight color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-embed

Does anybody know how to embed a Google map with my web page but not in Google's default red highlight color? I want to embed a Google map with my own favorite color which is blue!

Comment: Hi Dami, Do you want to change the color of map marker??

Comment: no i want to change search region highlight color which is by default showing in red

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot or create the fiddle for the reference??

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting what you want to customize exactly. But, I believe, definitely I can help you on this :)

So, please share either screenshot or create the fiddle for the reference.

Comment: yeah sure I know you help me out of this problem. My problem is that when we search any location on google map our search location is highlited by red outline with pink fill color, I want to embed map with highlited location but not in red or pink i want blue outline

Comment: like in this page you see sydney is highlited by red outline i just want to change this red color by blue
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90772/discussion-between-dami-and-rahul-kumar).

Comment: I don't think the Embed API allows you to specify any optional styles, at least not mentioned in their documentation.